# Scala Futures Returning Empty List after Await

Tags: list, scala, future

I have a program that performs an:

```scala
Await.result(Processor.validateEntries(queuedEntries)), Duration.Inf)
```

And the `validateEntries` method calls some other method that performs:

```scala
val validatedEntries: ListBuffer[Entries] = new ListBuffer[Entries]

for (entry <- queuedEntries) {
checkEntry(entry.name).map(.......... validatedEntries += Entries(...) )
}
Future(validatedEntries.toList)
```

where `checkEntry` returns a `Future[Boolean]`.

```scala
def checkEntry(name: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    checkNameAlreadyExists(name).flatMap(exists =>
        buildRequest(exists, name).map(response => {
            if (!response.contains("error")) {
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        })
    )
}
```

At the top level where I perform the `Await.result` I also get back an empty list: `List()`. Any suggestions would greatly help!

Comment: Could you please add full function ?

Comment: @VimitDhawan I edited the above

Answer (score 4):

Mixing mutable collections and concurrency is **not** a good idea. Consider refactoring `checkEntry` to return, say, `Future[Option[Entry]]` instead of `Future[Boolean]`, where `Some` would represent successful validation, whilst `None` unssucessful, and then you might do something like

```
case class Entry(v: Int)
val queuedEntries = List(Entry(1), Entry(2), Entry(3))
def checkEntry(entry: Entry): Future[Option[Entry]] = ???

Future
  .traverse(queuedEntries)(checkEntry)
  .map(_.flatten)
```

If keeping `checkEntry` as it is, then you might try something like

```
case class Entry(v: Int)
val queuedEntries = List(Entry(1), Entry(2), Entry(3))
def checkEntry(entry: Entry): Future[Boolean] = Future(Random.nextBoolean)

Future
  .traverse(queuedEntries)(checkEntry)
  .map(checkedEntries => checkedEntries zip queuedEntries)
  .map(_.collect { case (validated, entry) if validated => entry} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use for comprehension. Basically first you have to read the list and in yield, you have to call function one by one and wait for future to complete by yield

```
package com.vimit.StackOverflow

import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object FutureProblem extends App {


  val list = List(1, 2, 3)
  val outputList = List()

  val result = for {
    value <- list
  } yield {
    for {
      result <- getValue(value).map(res => outputList ++ List(value))
    } yield result
  }

  print(result)

  def getValue(value: Int) = Future(value)

}
```